# How to drag a JqueryUI dialog box outside the page

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I have a jqueryUI dialog box used to upload some files while the parent page allow users to fill some details. I want the dialog box to be moved out of the window of the parent to facilitate this. I have set the `modal` attribute to false to enable editing in the parent page. Is this possible? Any help is much appreciated.

This is the div i use as a dialog

`<div id="somediv" title="Attach files" style="display: none;">
 <iframe id="thedialog" width="350" height="350"></iframe>
 </div>`

notice that I have an iframe, in which src i will set next when i load the dialog essentially loading another page inside dialog box

```
$(".someClass").click(function () {
            $("#dialogBox").attr('src', $(this).attr("href") + "?EmailFolderPath=" + folderID);
            $("#myDiv").dialog({ 
                width: 400,
                height: 450,
                modal: false,
                close: function () { 
                }
            });
```

any idea how can i do this?

Comment: What is your code so far?

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't provide any code, I worked on something like this:

```
$.ui.dialog.prototype._makeDraggable = function() { 
this.uiDialog.draggable({
    containment: false,
    });
};
```

You just have to add this to your stylesheet!

```
body {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
overflow-y: hidden;
overflow-x: hidden;
}


html {
overflow-y: hidden;
background-color: transparent;
}
```

All I needed was to set the bottom and right as 0

For me it worked, it should work for too.

Comment: I have tried your solution but it didnt work as I am loading this dialog box inside another popup window, once i set the containment:false the whole page will be redirect to the page that i need to show inside the dialog.

Comment: Well, I don't use jQuery UI, so I can't help more than that, but, did you tried the jQuery Forum? Because your question didn't get a lot of views @LandMaster